# Blocking client IP in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I need to block certain client IP address say 1.2.3.4 and 2.3.4.5 to access "example.com/abc/def", but both can access example.com/.

The client IPs are behind the CloudFlare.

Client IP ==> CloudFlare ==> HAProxy

Answer (score 1):

Well basically first you need to define the acl. There you will specify the ip address or the CIDR you want to block.

```
acl block_ip src 1.2.3.4 32.42.51.62 45.56.67.7/16
```

Then another acl in which you will define the URL you want to restrict.

```
acl my_path path_beg -i /abc/def
```

then just use both the acl to block the user on that particular path

```
block if block_ip my_path
```

[here](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/haproxy_restrict_specific_urls_to_specific_ip_addresses.html) you can find more info on this.